# IntelliJ successfully infers types, but Compilation results in an inference error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, type-inference

I came accross an interesting issue recently when creating a Collector that goes from a `Stream<T>` to a `Map<K, T>`, similar to Guava's `Maps.uniqueIndex()` method. Here is the implementation and signature of my original method.

```
public static <T, K, M extends Map<K, T>> Collector<T, ?, M> toIdentityMap(Supplier<M> supplier, Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper) {
    return Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, Function.identity(), throwingMerger(), supplier);
}
```

A sample usage is as follows:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Stream.of("1", "2").stream().collect(toIdentityMap(HashMap::new, Integer::valueOf));
```

Now, with the current signature using `Function.identity()`, this code will be uncompilable according to both IntelliJ and Javac, but changing `Function.identity()` to a reference of the following will allow IntelliJ to infer the types correctly, with Javac failing.

```
private static <T> Function<? super T, ? extends T> identityCopy() {
    return Function.identity();
}
```

So this signature should be able to infer T, the reason being that when `Function.identity()` is casted to `Function<? super T, ? extends T>`manually in the original function compilation succeeds.

There are two fixes I know of, the explicit cast with the same type signature as the function above (which is effectively the same, the explicit cast vs. inferring). The first is to use a simple lambda of `e -> e` where inference would result in both sides of the function being `T` and the explicit cast described above.

Now, onto my guess of what is happening, which is what I would like to know, if we have a look at the signature of toMap:

```
public static <T, K, U, M extends Map<K, U>> Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                            Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                            BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                            Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

As we can see, the main difference is the type U, which is the value type in my definition T, and is in the Maps definition as T, so U == T right?

Now, is Java not able to infer that in this case a function of T to T is fine? What is going on here, and why can IntelliJ infer this?

Comment: Your first variant, using `Function.identity()` works fine for me; I could compile it successfully with all versions of `javac`, I could find. Besides that, there is no requirement to use a wildcard type, just because the target type has such a widened signature. Using `Function.<T>identity()` works fine as well. Consequently, using `ContainingClass.<T>identityCopy()` will work as well, but this helper method is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Interesting, I never actually attempted to compile it when IntelliJ displayed it as an error, however it does compile... http://postimg.org/image/h1gjckzor/